# Has Morrison's interpretation of the Phoenix Force been referenced?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, phoenix-force

I recently reread the ending of Morrison's run on New X-Men, the arc "*Here Comes Tomorrow*" , issues 151-154.  I hadn't quite understood the breadth of Morrison's reinterpretation of the Phoenix Force until this reading, and it seems like none of the subsequent writers have referenced any of these elements.

In light of the Phoenix's presence in Avengers vs X-men, this seems particularly important.  If Morrison's version of the Phoenix is canon, the Avengers are probably dramatically overreacting.

Have other writers referenced the New X-Men interpretation of the Phoenix Force?  Has it been explicitly retconned, or just swept under the rug, or is it still canon?

Bonus points if you can point me to places where Morrison's version of the Phoenix Force may have originated.  I know he loves his callbacks.

Comment: Nothing Grant Morrison writes is canon.

Comment: Fwiw, the avengers over-reacting was most of the impetus for AvX.  And that same over-reaction is what's been driving most x-books ever since.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information I've been able to gather Morrison's final run(issues 151-154) has been swept aside under the guise of not being Earth-616 but an alternate Earth-15104. The Phoenix Force group from inside the White Hot Room of the M'Kraan crystal was continued in the saga "Phoenix Endsong".

In [Phoenix Endsong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men%3a_Phoenix_%E2%80%93_Endsong) [#1](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men_Phoenix_Endsong_Vol_1_1)-[#5](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men_Phoenix_Endsong_Vol_1_5) they continue to show the destructive nature of the Phoenix.

However his killing of Jean Grey in issue 150 by Wolverine has been accepted and is where everything stands now.

http://marvel.wikia.com/Jean_Grey_(Earth-616)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_Comes_Tomorrow

Comment: Do you know where this might be referenced in the comics?  And, more specifically, does Endsong approach the Phoenix from the Morrison-style interpretation or the generic "bringer of doom" interpretation currently being seen in AvX?

Comment: @RedArrogantKnight when you ask for a comics reference are you asking do they come out and say they are on a different Earth?

Comment: It would be useful to see something that actually addresses the content of that timeline.  The events of "Here Comes Tomorrow" may have been in a timeline that is now defunct (thanks to the Phoenix's intervention) but that plot still reveals a great deal of backstory for Cassandra Nova, Quentin Quire, John Sublime and the Phoenix Force.  Lots of it doesn't seem to be canon anymore, but is that because the comics actually reference and alter the old material, or just because Wikipedia says it was an alternate timeline?